# A complicated OPERATOR equation

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, systems-of-equations, quantum-mechanics, semigroup-of-operators

I ended up in the following equation:

$J=2F^{\dagger}JF-F^{\dagger}FJ-JF^{\dagger}F$

where J is a known operator and F is unknown. 
I wanna specify that my operator are infinite dimensional. How do you approach the problem?

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to prove or solve for?

Comment: I'm trying to find out the class of F operators which satisfy the equation

Comment: Perhaps it's worth noting that $J \mapsto 2F^{\dagger}JF-F^{\dagger}FJ-JF^{\dagger}F - J$ is a linear operator

Comment: Also, if we were looking instead at
$$
J=2FJF^{\dagger}-F^{\dagger}FJ-JF^{\dagger}F
$$
then the equation cannot hold if $J$ and $F$ are trace-class operators.

Comment: Hi, brilliant. May you clarify your assertions? 
Why the map is linear and why the equation has no solution if $J$ and $F $ are trace class operators? (I noticed you swap the operators in the first term of the RHS)

Comment: Take the trace and use its cyclicality. But you said *J* is given. *Is it* finite dimensional?